# Flutter widget test error: OS Error: Read-only file system, errno = 30

Tags: flutter, testing, widget

when I use “flutter run xxx_test.dart”, I got an error:

> I/flutter (15574): The following FileSystemException was thrown
>   running a test:
>
> I/flutter (15574): Creation failed, path = '//.test' (OS Error:
>   Read-only file system, errno = 30)

since I call function:

```
dir.createSync(recursive: true);
```

how to resolve it? thx